# TODO app in Kotlin

Tags: beginner, kotlin, to-do-list

I'm learning Kotlin and I made a todo program (in command line) with Kotlin and Maven as my build tool.

[Full project](https://github.com/l-lin/ktodo).

### Description

The idea of my program is to read a file (path defined in a config file) that contains the list of tasks.

Since it's a project for practice purpose, the content of the file is quite simple and looks like this:

```
foo;true
bar;false
foobar;true
```

2 columns:

- Description of the task
- Status of the task

The only actions I've created are the following:

- **list** the tasks (on the standard output)
- **add** a new task (by writing a new line on the file)
- **finish** a task (by setting the status of the task to `true`)

There are also other options:

- **help**: display the list of options in the standard output
- **config**: use another configuration file
- **verbose**: display the debug logs
- **version**: display the version of the program

### The code

I'm using [commons CLI library](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/) to help me parse command line options passed in the arguments.

I represented a task with the following:

```
class Task(var name: String, var isDone: Boolean = false) {
    // Override toString to display the task in "human"
    override fun toString(): String {
        var done = ""
        if (isDone) {
            done = "X"
        }
        return "$name \t$done"
    }
    // function to transform the task in a line to be written in the file
    fun toLine(): String {
        return "$name$SEPARATOR$isDone"
    }
}
```

In order to transform a line from my task file into a `Task` instance, it's quite straightforward:

```
fun parse(line: String): Task {
    val array = line.split(SEPARATOR)
    if (array.size < 2) {
        return Task("", false)
    }
    return Task(sanitize(array[0]), sanitize(array[1]).toBoolean())
}

fun sanitize(s: String): String {
    return s.replace("\n", "")
}
```

I created an interface `Cmd` which represents a command:

```
interface Cmd {
    fun getOption(): Option
    fun isEnabled(line: CommandLine): Boolean
    fun getOptionValue(line: CommandLine): String?
}
```

I also created a `ActionCmd` which represents an action command, like adding, finishing, or listing the tasks. This `ActionCmd` implements the `Cmd` interface:

```
interface ActionCmd: Cmd {
    fun execute(p: Path, arg: String)
}
```

In order to avoid duplicating the code for all my commands, I created an abstract class `AbstractCmd` that uses the commons-CLI classes:

```
abstract class AbstractCmd: Cmd {
    override fun isEnabled(line: CommandLine): Boolean {
        return line.hasOption(getOption().longOpt)
    }

    override fun getOptionValue(line: CommandLine): String? {
        return line.getOptionValue(getOption().longOpt)
    }
}
```

Finally, the action commands are the following:

```
class ListCmd : AbstractCmd(), ActionCmd {
    private val option = Option("l", "list", false, "print the list of tasks")
    override fun getOption(): Option {
        return option
    }

    override fun execute(p: Path, arg: String) {
        val tasks = ArrayList<Task>()
        val stream = Files.newBufferedReader(p)
        stream.buffered().lines().forEach { line -> tasks.add(parse(line)) }
        tasks.forEach { println(it) }
    }
}

class AddCmd: AbstractCmd(), ActionCmd {
    private val option = Option("a", "add", true, "add a task")
    override fun getOption(): Option {
        return option
    }

    override fun execute(p: Path, arg: String) {
        // I have to add the empty string, otherwise, it's not going to add a new line
        p.toFile().appendText("" + Task(arg).toLine())
    }
}

class FinishCmd : AbstractCmd(), ActionCmd {
    private val option = Option("f", "finish", true, "finish a task")
    override fun getOption(): Option {
        return option
    }

    override fun execute(p: Path, arg: String) {
        val task = Task(arg)

        val tasks = ArrayList<Task>()
        val readerStream = Files.newBufferedReader(p)
        readerStream.buffered().lines().forEach { line ->
            val t = parse(line)
            if (t.name == task.name) {
                t.isDone = true
                debug("Finishing task: $t")
            }
            tasks.add(t)
        }
        File(p.toString()).printWriter().use { out ->
            tasks.forEach { out.println(it.toLine()) }
        }
    }
}
```

Does my code follow common best practices or am I going the wrong way?

Answer (score 4):

Here are some recommendations:

Use if as expression when it's appropriate.

```
var done = ""
if (isDone) {
    done = "X"
}
```

The better way is to write:

```
val done = if (isDone) "X" else ""
```

Also try to use val as much as it's possible. That will make your code simpler and more reliable.

Don't write obvious comments like comments for `toString` or `toLine` functions.

I would rename functions `toLine` and `parse` to `serialize`/`deserialize`. Or I'd use just `toString` + `parse`.

Using global variables like `SEPARATOR` is a bad idea.

I'd recommend use `data class` for Task and Commands.

```
private val option = Option("a", "add", true, "add a task")
override fun getOption(): Option {
    return option
}
```

It equals to

```
val option = Option("a", "add", true, "add a task")
```

Also it's a good practice to avoid using in functions many arguments with the same type. If you can't avoid you still can name them explicitly by writing `method(param = arg1..)`

This looks weird

```
p.toFile().appendText("" + Task(arg).toLine())
```

Try to use more filters, maps, and other hi-order functions over collections

```
val tasks = ArrayList<Task>()
val stream = Files.newBufferedReader(p)
stream.buffered().lines().forEach { line -> tasks.add(parse(line)) }
tasks.forEach { println(it) }
```

This is just:

```
p.toFile().readLines().map{ parse(it) }.forEach {
    println(it)
}
```

Another example:

```
    val tasks = ArrayList<Task>()
    val readerStream = Files.newBufferedReader(p)
    readerStream.buffered().lines().forEach { line ->
        val t = parse(line)
        if (t.name == task.name) {
            t.isDone = true
            debug("Finishing task: $t")
        }
        tasks.add(t)
    }
```

Is just

```
val tasks = p!!.toFile().readLines().map { parse(it) }
commands.filter { it.name == task.name }.forEach { it.isDone = true }
```

If you want I can rewrite your program on my taste (as example).

Comment: "Using global variables like SEPARATOR is a bad idea."

I wanted to use a constant, not a global variable. What should be done instead?

`val option = Option("a", "add", true, "add a task")`


The `getOption` method was declared in the interface as I needed to abstract the implentation when fetching all the options.